# Reducing package size

Tags: mpdf

I want to include mPDF into my WordPress plugin to enable some export to PDF features. However the mPDF files are pretty large at ~98mb.

Are there only specific files I can include to retain exporting to HTML and keeping the formatting? For example, I assume I can remove the fonts I will not be needed. Even then the overall package size is still pretty large. Can any other files/folders be omitted?

Answer (score 7):

Mike,

You can delete all fonts from 'ttfonts' directory and retain only the ones you require. If you are not using any fonts, you can just retain DejaVu fonts and delete others, which will reduce the size of fonts directory from 86.8MB to 8MB & overall library size to 20MB(approx) from 98MB.